# Can't find RPostgreSQL.so in Mac Big Sur in R

Tags: r, postgresql, macos

I tried to run my R code after upgrading the operating system from Mojave to Big Sur. When trying this simple code:

```
library("RPostgreSQL")
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RPostgreSQL’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object 
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/RPostgreSQL/libs/RPostgreSQL.so'
```

I forgot to make a time machine copy (which is a hard lesson). Please, do you know how can I install that so file and where I can find it? I tried reinstalling `install.packages("RPostgreSQL")` but I get the same error message. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of R and it should work just fine